# KTM Duke 200, Broken Airbox

Tags: motorcycle, air-intake, air-filter, ktm

My duke generates an odd noise and when I looked under my seat what I saw was an open air filter box because of the broken screws. When I took my bike to the service center what they told was to replace the air box completely which costs 3k. Is it okay that I fix this by applying some glue temporarily ? or how should i solve it?

Comment: Welcome to the site. It would be a tremendous help if you post up some pictures of the damage. Thanks!

Comment: I have to wonder what currency that 3k is in.  Rupee?

Comment: 3k potatoes! Anyways, do post pictures, answer is impossible otherwise.

Comment: Yes, please post a picture.  Is it the cover that retains the air filter in place within the airbox when you screw the cover down?  Also what year is your Duke?

Comment: Sorry guys, I didn't make my question clear. Cost of replacing the airbox will be 3000 INR.

Comment: @user3248119  In relation to your other question.  Is the airbox even in the bike anymore?  If it's not, your bike is probably running lean.  Once you reply to my last couple of questions I can probably point you in the right direction regarding fixing this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Provided it is not a stressed or load bearing member...

You should be ok glueing or plastic welding it however you like. As long as it is securely attached to the bike. You can probably drill holes in it and use cable ties to hold it in place. Beyond that its really about what it looks like and how much it bothers you.

However the important part is to ensure that the filter element seals properly with the engine intake so that all air drawn into the engine is filtered. If it isnt then dust and other fine material will be sucked into your engine which will increase wear and reduce the life of your engine.

Comment: How to know whether too much dust getting into the engine?

Comment: Ideally you dont want *any* dust to get into the engine. Its a bit hard to explain without a picture but ALL air should go through the filter into the intake. How it gets into the airbox doesnt matter. If you can see a gap, hole or opening that allows air into the engine without being filtered you have a problem.

Comment: Remove the filter and wipe you finger or a piece of white cloth around the inside of the intake. Can you see dirt/dust on your finger? A little smudge is normal a black finger/cloth indicates you need to clean/oil/replace or repair your filter.

Answer (score 2):

If you think you can seal the box dust proof by glue, go right ahead and do that. I've had mine broke two years back and applied silicon sealant. Just that it's a bit tough later on when you're changing air filter.